# Can't Install PrivateerGold1.03.bz2.bin

Tags: installation, games

I downloaded a Linux friendly game called **Privateer Gemini Gold**. I have the file in my "Downloads" folder.

**First question:** When I start my terminal, and I type `LS`, downloads appear to be in my home directory. Do I need to change directory or something first?

**Second question:** I try to install the program, by typing `sudo sh downloads/PrivateerGold1.03.bz2.bin`. I have tried without the `sh` command as well, but neither command works. I even tried writing the full path but that didn't work either. It keeps telling me it can't open the file. The spelling is correct, I've tried it about 30 times and I am getting very frustrated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Strange it appears to be compressed with it having bz2 in the extension but the .bin at the end would suggest its executable.

Try first of all making the file executable you can do this by running the command

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/PrivateerGold1.03.bz2.bin
```

You can run in then by typing:

```
~/Downloads/PrivateerGold1.03.bz2.bin
```

if this does not work try extrating the file with:

```
tar -xvjf  ~/Downloads/PrivateerGold1.03.bz2.bin ~/Downloads
```

You will then have to tell me what you get out of that.

Comment: It's common to have a binary executable (and sometimes even a shell script) with the binary data for a `.bz2` or other archive embedded in it. That's probably what's going on here, so marking it executable and running it, as you advise, should work quite well.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks, I haven't come accross it before but makes sense to me.

Comment: thanks for helping me install the game. It extracted, and I seem to have been able to install it, and it's installed into where I wanted it. I am wondering what else I need to do? and how do I play the game now?

Comment: @Peter What happened when ran it? Did it extract or run through an installer?